# Java - send an XML file over TCP/IP. is it possible?

Tags: java, xml, networking, tcp

I am writing an application where one of the processes is to send data over tcp/ip. I was going to/have wrapped my data into an xml file, but here is my question(s):

1. is it actually possible to send a xml file over as a whole or do i need to read it line by line?
2. if so how would i go about it/which methods should i use?

Comment: The Java [Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) and [IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) tutorials may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The attempt often used is to read N bytes from the file, then send them and then read N more bytes, ignoring the check if this is a new line or not, as it doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 1):

> is it actually possible to send a xml file over as a whole or do i need to read it line by line?

A TCP socket has a stream of bytes and you notionally send one byte at a time. This means you can't send a file over a socket, but you can send all the bytes in a file and create another file with the same bytes if you want, possibly with the same name or even in the same directory path.

Most XML writers and parsers support OutputStream and InputStream or Writer and Reader.  If you use those you don't need to know how or when a byte is send nor should you care.